# How to get the last point or current point from a uibezierpath?

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

I am adding a line from point to point.

```
...
[self->path addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
//need to check the point(x,y) against another point ?? 

[self setNeedsDisplay];
...
```

How to extract the last point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` has a property called `currentPoint`.

For more info take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/currentPoint).